# How do I get text that isn't wrapped in <p> tags to copy using XSLT?

Tags: xslt-2.0

I'm running an XSLT script to update questions to a newer format. The authors did not wrap the explanations in `<p>` tags. When I run the script those explanations drop out. If I wrap them in `<p>` tags they copy over just fine. I have 1200 questions so I'm really hoping not to have to wrap all the explanations in `<p>` tags one-by-one.

```
<!-- attributes, commments, processing instructions, text: copy as is -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|comment()|processing-instruction()|/text()">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>


<xsl:if test="*[not(@property)]">
<section property="ktp:explanation-section" typeof="ktp:feedback" data-title="Feedback">
<xsl:attribute name="class">
     <xsl:text>ktp-explanation-section</xsl:text>
     <!-- append exclusion class, if any -->
     <xsl:if test="string-length($exclusions)!=0">
     <xsl:value-of select="$exclusions"/>
     </xsl:if>
     </xsl:attribute> 
     <xsl:attribute name="data-uuid">
      <xsl:call-template name="assignID"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(@property)]|text()"/>
       </section>
```

Comment: Please show a minimal but representative and complete XML input sample and the corresponding result you wan to create. Then also a minimal but complete XSLT that currently creates the wrong output.

Comment: Talking about `<p>` let me think you are trying to parse HTML content. Are you aware that HTML isn't XML? HTML *may* be xml compatible, but it's not in the specs. Especially with HTML5, nothing guarantees you the content will be be readable as XML content. In this case, if I'm right, I suggest you to take a look at [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) which is a must have library (.net); There's probably equivalent libs in other languages, but you didn't mentioned your context